# JS condition to hide an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have this cool script which filters a list of words when some one types inside an input some letters, I really hope this will be also useful for other people.

You can see it in action here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t7VEu/)

**My code:**

```
<input id="filter" />
<ul id="productlist">
    <li><h2>Andy</h2><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><h2>Sandra</h2><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><h2>Pizza</h2><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><h2>Drink</h2><span>some text</span></li>
</ul>

var $products = $('#productlist li h2');
$('#filter').keyup(function() {
    var re = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i"); // "i" means it's case-insensitive
    $products.show().filter(function() {
        return !re.test($(this).text());
    }).hide();
});
```

So i need it to hide not only H2 but the whole li element with the content inside it.

PS: please dont tell me to change from **var $products = $('#productlist li h2');** to var **$products = $('#productlist li');**
i need the search to work only for h2 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```
var $products = $('#productlist li');
$('#filter').keyup(function() {
    var re = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i"); // "i" means it's case-insensitive
    $products.show().filter(function() {
        return !re.test($('h2',this).text());
    }).hide();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7CVgL/

(Note: Ive done what you asked me not to do, but it still searches only the content of the `h2` element)

Comment: it hides for EVER... after an elemt was hiddent it will never become visible if a new search is made.... in my example this is not happening: http://jsfiddle.net/t7VEu/